# Need to return Scrapy callback method data to calling function

Tags: scrapy

In below code I am trying to collect email ids from a website. It can be on contact or about us page.
From parse method I follow extemail method for all those pages.
From every page I collected few email ids.
Now I need to print them with original record sent to **init** method.

For example:
record = "https://www.wockenfusscandies.com/"

I want to print output as,
https://www.wockenfusscandies.com/|abc@gamil.com|def@outlook.com

I am not able to store them in self.emails and deliver back to **init** method.

Please help.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class EmailSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    def __init__(self, record):
        self.record = record
        self.emails = []

        url = record.split("|")[4]

        if not url.startswith("http"):
            url = "http://{}".format(url)

        if url:
            self.start_urls = ["https://www.wockenfusscandies.com/"]
        else:
            self.start_urls = []

    def parse(self, response):
        contact_list = [a.attrib['href'] for a in response.css('a') if 'contact' in a.attrib['href'] or 'about' in a.attrib['href']]
        contact_list.append(response.request.url)

        for fllink in contact_list:
            yield response.follow(fllink, self.extemail)

    def extemail(self, response):
        emails = response.css('body').re('[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+')
        yield {
            'emails': emails
        }

process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})
f = open("/Users/kalpesh/work/data/test.csv")
for rec in f:
    process.crawl(EmailSpider, record=rec)
f.close()
process.start()
```

Comment: You don't do anything with `self.emails`. Can you clarify what you want to do here?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intend correctly you could try the following proceeding:

a) collect the mail-ids in self.emails like

```
def extemail(self, response):
    emails = response.css('body').re('[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+')
    self.emails = emails.copy()
    yield {
        'emails': emails
    }
```

(Or on what other way you get the email-ids from `emails`)

b) add a close(self, reason) method as in [GitHub-Example](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py#L101) which is called when the spider has finished

```
def close(self, reason):
    mails_for_record = ""

    for mail in self.emails:
        mails_for_record += mail + "|"

    print(self.record + mails_for_record)
```

Please also note, I read somewhere that for some versions of Scrapy it is `def close(self, reason)`, for others it is `def closed(self, reason)`.

Hope, this proceeding helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You should visit all the site pages before yielding result for this one site.
This means that you should have queue of pages to visit and results storage.
It can be done using meta.

Some pseudocode:

```
def parse(self, response):
    meta = response.meta
    if not meta.get('seen'):
    # -- finding urls of contact and about us pages --
    # -- putting it to meta['queue'] --
    # -- setting meta['seen'] = True

    page_emails_found = ...getting emails here...
    # --- extending already discovered emails 
    # --- from other pages/initial empty list with new ones
    meta['emails'].extend(page_emails_found)

    # if queue isn't empty - yielding new request
    if meta['queue']:
       next_url = meta['queue'].pop()
       yield Request(next_url, callback=self.parse, meta=copy(meta))
    # if queue is empty - yielding result from meta
    else:
       yield {'url': current_domain, 'emails': meta['emails']}
```

Something like this..